# Query the Kafka KTable from out side the Application

Tags: java, rest, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am in situation where have 5 Streaming applications running in Kafka Cluster and all applications have one final output Kafka topics each. Now i need to write some REST services to access those final KTables outside the application. I am able to run this [application](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/4.0.0-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/interactivequeries/kafkamusic/KafkaMusicExample.java) but it needs to create a streaming application accesing the final output topic. 
Is there any possible way to access these state store in external rest application?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by " Is there any possible way to access the streaming application itself?" ?

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski i have changed the question. I was thinking about creating some rest service that can access this application state store and query from it

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to access something like KTable directly from kafka broker, without having first to stream all data into local memory?

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski yes...i am trying to write that service

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no direct way to access the state stores in external application.

The state stores are built on top of the changelog topic, so you can use the changelog topic in your external application to get the flavour of state store in compacted way.

Another possible option would be implementing your own custom external stores.